# CLI to set variable of env file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

There is a `.env` file which looks like this:

```
VAR1=1
VAR2=2
VAR3=3
```

Now I would like to change a specific value in shell like this

```
cli set .env VAR2 foo
```

should give me the result

```
VAR1=1
VAR2=foo
VAR3=3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a single line CLI which does what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

operation=$1
file=$2
var=$3
value=$4
[[ "$operation" = "set" ]] && sed "s/^\($var\)=.*/\1=$value/" "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand your question properly, but here is my answer...

If you want to use environment variables, the best thing you can do is exporting them. If you want to keep this **.env** file, for example in your home directory, you could simply add this to your **.bashrc**:

`source ~/.env`

Then, you can use the following commands to manipulate your variables:

- `env` to display all environment variables
- `echo $VAR1` to display the value of a specific variable
- `export VAR2=foo` to change the value of a given variable in the current shell session

If you want to make changes permanent, you can use sed:

```
sed -i '/VAR2/c\export VAR2=bar' .env
```

Comment: To make the match more specific `sed -i '/^VAR2=/....` - only match at the beginning of line, and include '='